# Why Chrome shows the listeners count is smaller than actual it has?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, reactjs, listener

I have code like this:

```
function ManyNodes() {
  const nums = new Array(1e5).fill(0).map(_ => Math.floor(Math.random()*1e8));
  return (
  <ul>{nums.map(n => <li key={n} onClick={e=>console.log(n)}>{n}</li>)}</ul>
  )
}

render(<ManyNodes />, document.querySelector('#app'))
```

Then it should 1e5 `li` in the document and every `li` has its own click listeners. So there should be more than 1e5 listeners on the page.

But I use Chrome Web Developer Tool, and in its `Performance` tab, you can see just hundreds of listeners. That's strange.

How react handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*TL;DR* Event Delegation and Event Pooling

**Event Delegation**

> Attaching event listeners to DOM nodes is painfully slow and
>   memory-consuming. Instead, React implements a popular technique called
>   "event delegation".

What is Event Delegation?

> A single event listener is attached to the root of the document. When
>   an event is fired, the browser gives us the target DOM node [...]

For you information, *Vjeux* is a Facebook Software Engineer in the Front-end team working on React Native.

http://blog.vjeux.com/2013/javascript/react-performance.html (check Event Delegation section)

**Event pooling**

> The SyntheticEvent is pooled. This means that the SyntheticEvent
>   object will be reused and all properties will be nullified after the
>   event callback has been invoked. This is for performance reasons. As
>   such, you cannot access the event in an asynchronous way.

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html